# Is there a way to find out which records have changed in an indexed view?

Tags: sql-server, indexed-view

I have a table (`invoice details`) which has two columns (`productid` and `quantity`). I created an indexed view on this table in order to know the balance of products.

When a user enters an invoice on a computer, I want to refresh the product balance on another computer, so I need to know which rows in the indexed view were changed.

Comment: There is no way - your view aggregates values (presumably) so you cannot know which rows changed. In fact, you could have a situation where multiple detail rows changed for a give invoice but the subtotal amount remains the same. Or a detail row is deleted and a new one inserted (whether subtotal changes or not). Are you making assumptions here that are valid?

Comment: Thank you
The realistic scenario is more complex than the example I mentioned. But I just wanted to know the possibility of knowing the changes in Indexed view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactional Replication allows you to replicate [Indexed Views as Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects).  This will track changes to the indexed view and apply them to the subscribers, who have a copy of the indexed view data as a table in the subscriber database.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. You pull (regularly) and update. Any application that needs to distribute data updates that I have ever seen does not do it by updating from SQL Server, but does so by sending updates on their own data feeds implemented by an application server - mostly stock trading applications.

SQL Server has no functionality for this, nor does pretty much every db access layer I have ever seen. You repull and update the in client representation, either regularly (every X seconds) or when the user presses an update button.

Comment: This is what I do now, but it's tiring if many indexes views. Anyway, thank you for your valuable answer